# Python pandas calculation over a list of dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

I am using python and pandas to do some data handling.

For a list of dataframes "dfc" read from csvs, I am trying to run the following:

```
dfc = []
for filename in filenames:
    dfc.append(pd.read_csv(filename, names=columns, header=None, delim_whitespace=True))

for dataset in dfc:
    dataset = dataset[dataset.dB != 0]
    dataset = dataset[dataset.B < 0]
    dataset = dataset.dropna()
    dataset = dataset.drop(dataset[(dataset['dB'] + dataset['dB'].shift(+1)) == 0].index)
    dataset = dataset.reset_index(drop=True)
        
for dataset in dfc:
    display(dataset)
```

Although this code runs on a single data-frame, it doesn't loop over the list of data-frames. If I just run one every instance, it works though.

Answer (score 1):

After creating the list of dataframes, run them all through a function instead of trying to loop through them in a way that won't modify them.

```
def do_stuff(data):
    df = data.copy()
    df = df[df.dB != 0]
    df = df[df.B < 0]
    df = df.dropna()
    df = df.drop(df[(df['dB'] + df['dB'].shift(+1)) == 0].index)
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    return df

dfc = [do_stuff(df) for df in dfc]
```

---

Unsolicited changes I would make:

```
def do_stuff(df):
    df = df[df.dB.ne(0) & df.B.lt(0)].dropna()
    df = df[~df[df.dB.add(df.dB.shift(1)).eq(0)]]
    return df.reset_index(drop=True)
```